# Appcelerator Studio Cannot Detect Valid iOS nor Android SDK on Mac

Tags: android, ios, sdk, titanium, appcelerator

Even though XCode, iOS and Android SDKs are installed. Appcelerator does not detects iOS nor Android SDKs and displays error:

> Could not detect a valid SDK with version '6' or higher at '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs

I installed the latest Appcelerator Studio, Oracle JDK 8, NodeJS 12.16.2, XCode 10.1, Android Studio 3.6.2

I tried reinstalling Appcelerator Studio, Oracle JDK, Node JS, setting the sdk path under preferences-Platforms and restarting my Mac multiple times and I still get the same error.

Here is the appc info from the Terminal:

```
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 8.0.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2020, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.13.6
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 4.0GB

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 12.16.2
  npm Version                 = 6.14.4

Appcelerator CLI
  Installer                   = 5.0.0
  Core Package                = 8.0.0

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.2.2
  node-appc Version           = 0.2.49

Titanium SDKs
  9.0.0.GA
    Version                   = 9.0.0
    Install Location          = /Users/posuna/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.0.0.GA
    Platforms                 = iphone, android
    git Hash                  = ff53751424
    git Timestamp             = 3/4/2020 14:47
    node-appc Version         = 0.3.4

Mac OS X
  Command Line Tools          = installed

Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
  Not installed

Java Development Kit
  Version                     = 1.8.0_241
  Java Home                   = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home

Genymotion
  Path                        = not found
  Genymotion Executable       = not found
  Genymotion Player           = not found
  Home                        = not found

VirtualBox
  Executable                  = not found
  Version                     = unknown

Android SDK
  Android Executable          = not found
  ADB Executable              = not found
  SDK Path                    = not found

Android NDK
  NDK Path                    = not found
  NDK Version                 = not found

Android Platforms
  None

Android Add-Ons
  None

Android Emulators
  None

Genymotion Emulators
  None

Connected Android Devices
  None

Xcode
  10.1 (build 10B61) - Xcode default
    Install Location          = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    iOS SDKs                  = 12.1
    iOS Simulators            = none
    Watch SDKs                = 5.1
    Watch Simulators          = none
    Supported by TiSDK 9.0.0.GA = yes
    EULA Accepted             = yes
    Teams                     = none
```

[image: iOS settings]

[image: Android settings]

[image: iOS SDK files]

[image: Android SDK files]

Comment: there is already a ticket about this issue: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-9214 Keep an eye on that for a solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get both the IOS and Android SDK working after giving my user read & write permissions to the `~/.config` folder and making sure both the Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Build Tools were installed under the Android SDK folder.

After starting appcelerator in debug the terminal outputed the error:

```
2020-04-20T21:53:20.877Z appcd:default-plugins:lerna error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/ Users/posuna/.config/yarn/link'".
```

I fixed the error after following these steps below suggested on the axway community here: [Axway Community](https://community.axway.com/s/question/0D73V000000Ha4S/appcelerator-studio-cannot-detect-valid-ios-nor-android-sdk?s1oid=00Dw0000000CxUA&s1nid=0DBw0000000fySH&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&s1uid=0053V000000YUEI&emtm=1587432469350&fromEmail=1&s1ext=0)

1. Give your user read & write permissions to the "~/.config" folder by control+click on the folder, then click "GetInfo", then "Sharing & Permissions", then add your username with Read & Write privilege, then under the setting click apply to enclosed items. In my mac this is a hidden folder on the path "Macintosh HD/Users/MyUsername/.config"
2. Shut down Appcelerator Studio completely.
3. In the terminal run the command "appc appcd stop"
4. Delete the folder "~/.appcelerator/appcd/plugins". In my mac this is a hidden folder on the path "Macintosh HD/Users/MyUsername/"
5. Run the command "appc appcd start --debug"
6. Once you start seeing the CPU parameters as part of the above command start Appcelerator Studio again and check preferences->Studio->Platforms->iOS. It should recognize the iOS sdk on the specified path. In my case is "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer"

Comment: It helped me. You are amazing!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
Solved it by creating a symbolic link.
In my case:
ln -s  /Users/ronnyvanelewyck/Library/android-sdk-macosx  /Users/ronnyvanelewyck/Library/Android/sdk

Apparently the deamon was looking for Android only in /Users/ronnyvanelewyck/Library/Android/sdk.

regards
Ronny